# How can I install Ubuntu 13.10 on Asus n56dp-dh11

Tags: laptop, uefi, asus

My laptop has uefi and when I open the bios there is no clear way to tell the computer to boot from USB or CD. I'm very confused on how I'm supposed to install anything, even windows 7 can not load from a USB drive or DVD. I've seen, after a few hours of Googling that Ubuntu and other Linux distro's run great on this very exact laptop. But they have no insight as to how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down either F8, F9, F10, F11, or F12 just after you boot your laptop, one of them should take you to a boot selection screen.

Comment: I tried f1 all the way to f12, none of them did anything except for f2, which took me to the bios....but the problem is that the bios for this computer does not allow you to load from a cd or a usb.